# How Do I Continue a Conversation if Someone Mentions Something Interesting in an Answer?

Tags: discussion, meta, users

Say I'm reading questions and answers, and someone like @Graham, mentions something about how the crazy Aussies don't chill.  So I want to touch base with Graham and find out about it.  It would be 'noise' if we started a discussion inside the question.  So where/how is that conversation supposed to take place?

--Dale--

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scroll down to the bottom of the page. There, cleverly hidden midst about 10,000 other links, is one labelled "[chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/)". Click it, & you'll see one or more rooms available for idle conversation about whatever you feel like...

Pick an existing room or create one of your own, and then copy the URL into a comment on the answer you're interested in staring a tangential discussion from. If the other person / people want to join in, they can follow the link and converse with you in the room.

Comment: link is also at the top of the page, except when a per-site blog has a post...

Comment: Great answer, some features are not really that prominent.

Comment: Yes! Chat is perfect for this. Tag the user in your comment as well and invite them personally for best results.